# Multiple RouteHandler for a Route

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-router

I need to show multiple nav-items based on the route.
For example

```
var routes = (
 <Route path="/" handler={Wrapper}>
  <Route handler={NavItemMenu} />
  <Route handler={NavItemSave}/>
 </Route>
);
```

And use it something like this

```
var Nav = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="p-nav-left">
         <ul className="p-navbar-nav">
          <RouteHandler/>   
         </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
   });
```

I was expecting it to show both "NavItemMenu" and "NavItemSave".

Similarly I want to show different items for different paths. 
How do I do this? For a single route how do I create Multiple Handler?

Comment: Would you not just include those components inside the Wrapper handler? You can require them and then do `<NavItemMenu />` and `<NavItemSave />`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a case of nesting, but of alternate routes based on the value of something -- maybe a prop passed in to `Wrapper`? I'm having to guess a little here, but maybe this is what you want?

```
let Wrapper = React.createClass({
    // bunch of code omitted
    render() {
        let contents = null;
    if (this.props.some_value === "x") {
        contents = <NavItemMenu />
    } else {
        contents = <NavItemSave />
    }
    return contents;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is not the right way to do. 
For example if a page has components A, B, C and now when you move to a different page, and it has components A, D, E.
I cant achieve this using react-router

Comment: Also component B has multiple sub components B1 B2 B3 B4.
for a certain Route i only want to show B1 and B2.